# spin parity $J^P$ notation

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, notation, parity

In particle physics, when you read $J^P$, does it mean Spin parity or total angular momentum parity?

I know that the letter $J$ is used for TOTAL angular momentum but I think I read somewhere that sometimes it is meant spin when used in this $J^P$ notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation always refers to the total angular momentum. A source of confusion may be that in nuclear physics, we talk about the "spin" of a nucleus as a whole, even though the spin is only partly due to the intrinsic spin 1/2 of the neutrons and protons.